# inner join 4 tables mysql C#

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I really need a help. To begin with i'd like to present what's the problem :

```
General Table:
create table cworkdb.models(
    model_id integer auto_increment,
    model_name varchar(40) not null,
    man_id integer not null,
    cpu_id integer not null,
    ram_quantity integer not null,
    hdd_capacity integer not null,
    video_id integer not null,
    primary key(model_id),
    foreign key(man_id) references manufacturers(man_id),
    foreign key(cpu_id) references cpu_comp(cpu_id),
    foreign key(video_id) references videocard(video_id)
);
```

And 3 tables(which I have link to):

```
create table cworkdb.manufacturers(
    man_id integer auto_increment,
    man_name varchar(50) not null,
    primary key(man_id)
);
create table cworkdb.videocard(
    video_id integer auto_increment,
    video_name varchar(45) not null,
    video_memory double not null,
    primary key(video_id)
)
create table cworkdb.cpu_comp(
    cpu_id integer auto_increment,
    cpu_name varchar(60) not null,
    cpu_freq double not null,
    primary key(cpu_id)
);
```

My selectQuery string  -

```
string selectQuery = "select model_id, model_name, man_name, cpu_name,ram_quantity,hdd_capacity,video_name"
                                 + "from (cworkdb.models inner join cworkdb.cpu_comp on cworkdb.models.cpu_id=cworkdb.cpu_comp.cpu_id)"
                                 +"inner join cworkdb.manufacturers on cworkdb.models.man_id=cworkdb.manufacturers.man_id"
                                 +"inner join cworkdb.videocard on cworkdb.models.video_id=cworkdb.videocard.video_id";
```

When I'm trying to use this in MySqlCommand - an error is thrown:

> the problem is near first inner join.

Although I modified (deleted first brackets), it still says there's an error. Where did I make the mistake? Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: add a space at the end of all rows

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realized that spaces should be at the end of all lines. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have write this:

```
string selectQuery = "select model_id, model_name, man_name, cpu_name,ram_quantity,hdd_capacity,video_name"
                             + "from (cworkdb.models inner join cworkdb.cpu_comp on cworkdb.models.cpu_id=cworkdb.cpu_comp.cpu_id)"
                             +"inner join cworkdb.manufacturers on cworkdb.models.man_id=cworkdb.manufacturers.man_id"
                             +"inner join cworkdb.videocard on cworkdb.models.video_id=cworkdb.videocard.video_id";
```

but you're missing the space at the end of row (or if you want at the start of row), so when you concatenate the strings inner join is attached to )

So write this:

```
string selectQuery = "select model_id, model_name, man_name, cpu_name,ram_quantity,hdd_capacity,video_name "
                             + "from (cworkdb.models inner join cworkdb.cpu_comp on cworkdb.models.cpu_id=cworkdb.cpu_comp.cpu_id) "
                             +"inner join cworkdb.manufacturers on cworkdb.models.man_id=cworkdb.manufacturers.man_id "
                             +"inner join cworkdb.videocard on cworkdb.models.video_id=cworkdb.videocard.video_id";
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add spaces to your SQL sentences.

```
string selectQuery = "select model_id, model_name, man_name, cpu_name,ram_quantity,hdd_capacity,video_name "
                             + "from (cworkdb.models inner join cworkdb.cpu_comp on cworkdb.models.cpu_id=cworkdb.cpu_comp.cpu_id) "
                             +"inner join cworkdb.manufacturers on cworkdb.models.man_id=cworkdb.manufacturers.man_id "
                             +"inner join cworkdb.videocard on cworkdb.models.video_id=cworkdb.videocard.video_id";
```